# How to use character value in if condition (c++)

Tags: c++, loops, while-loop, character

```
    {
        cout << "type 3 to add ,type 1 to multiply,type division to divide,type 2 to subtract" << endl;

        cin >> function;

        if (function == 1)
        {
            multiply();
        }

        else if (function == 2)
        {
            subtract();
        }
        else if (function == 3)
        {
            add();
        }
        else if (function == 4)
        {
            division();
        }

        cout << "press x to quit or anything else to restart " << endl;
        cin >> input;
    } while (input !='x');

    system("pause");
    return 0;
}
```

in this code i am unable to have a character value with if
eg-if `(function=='add')` it does not work
if I use `if(function='add')` everything inside is skipped to the last `cout` which says

> press x to quit or anything else to restart

Comment: where is function defined? is it a char? an int? see https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve

Comment: What is `function`?

Comment: function='add' is not within your conditions, so it shouldn't strike you that it skips all of them

Comment: @Detonar: Not really: it's actually a multi-character literal.

Comment: @Detonar: Absolutely not. "add"  is a const char[4] type with an added NUL-terminator. 'add' is a multicharacter literal with type `int`.

Comment: Please provide a [Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable](https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve) example. Naming a variable `function` is misleading.

Comment: You're confusing characters with strings. A string is a sequence of characters.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`'add'` is a *multicharacter literal* and is an `int` type (note the single quotation characters). You almost certainly don't want to do that as then you're in the murky waters of *implementation-defined* behaviour.

If you want to be able to read in strings then why not use a `std::string` as the type for `function`, and use `if (function == "add")` &c. ? You can even retain your notation `cin >> function`!

Answer (score 0):

As suggested by Bathsheba, you could implement this functionality with std::string. Bellow you have an example of how you could do this.

```
#include <iostream>
#include <string>

void multiply() {
    std::cout << "multiplication called" << std::endl;
}
void add() {
    std::cout << "add called" << std::endl;
}
void subtract() {
    std::cout << "substract called" << std::endl;
}
void division() {
    std::cout << "division called" << std::endl;
}

int main()
{
    using namespace std;
    string input;

    do {
        cout << "type add, multiply, division, or subtract" << endl;
        cin >> input;

        if (input == "multiply") {
            multiply();
        }
        else if (input == "substract") {
            subtract();
        }
        else if (input == "add") {
            add();
        }
        else if (input == "division") {
            division();
        }
        else {
            cout << "You inputed: " << input << endl;
            cout << "Command not recognized, please try again" << endl;
            continue;
        }

        cout << "press x to quit or anything else to restart ";
        cin >> input;

    } while (input != "x");

    return 0;
}
```